# How can I safely "inject" values to my query WHERE clause (Python, Pandas)?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following query:

```
q = "SELECT id, age, weight, status from my_table"
```

`conn` is given.
I would like to add a `WHERE` clause with some params I will get from the users (securely).
For example `WHERE id = 64 AND status=4` or any other combination I will pass to it.

This query is part of a function:

```
import pandas as pd

def customized_q(params):

    return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn, params)
```

I want the end result to take the params with their values and add to `WHERE` clause with `AND` operator.

For example if `params = {'id':64, 'status':4}` it will be translated to a modified q:

```
"SELECT id, age, weight, status from my_table WHERE id=5 AND status=4"
```

Please advise how can I achieve it?

Comment: maybe sqlmodel can help you. https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create the WHERE clause on the fly, based on the `params`:

```
query = "SELECT id, age, weight, status from my_table WHERE "
query += ' AND '.join([f'{k}={v}' for k,v in params.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you will always have an ID and a status you could do the following. However, this would only work if you knew every time both params would not be null. if they weren't you would have to back in some additional logic

````
query = f"""
SELECT 
    id, 
    age,
    weight, 
    status 
from my_table 
WHERE 1=1
    and id = {params['id']}
    AND status = {params['status']}
"""
print(query)
```
````